# why app created with react native cli command contain type script in app.js file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

```
import type {Node} from 'react';

const Section = ({children, title}): Node => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  return (
    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionTitle,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          },
        ]}>
        {title}
      </Text>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionDescription,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.light : Colors.dark,
          },
        ]}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const App: () => Node = () => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'} />
      <ScrollView
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        style={backgroundStyle}>
        <Header />
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          }}>
          <Section title="Step One">
            Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.js</Text> to change this
            screen and then come back to see your edits.
          </Section>
          <Section title="See Your Changes">
            <ReloadInstructions />
          </Section>
          <Section title="Debug">
            <DebugInstructions />
          </Section>
          <Section title="Learn More">
            Read the docs to discover what to do next:
          </Section>
          <LearnMoreLinks />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

i created a fresh app with npx react-native init myAppName command i opened app js file
to make changes , but i found typescript code in
the import statement and const section node , const app node are typescript , did i created typescript app??
or it's still react native cli , is it gonna create any issues in future of this app

Answer (score 0):

It is not typescript, but [Flow](https://flow.org/), a static type checker for js. The errors are probably due to the IDE, you are using. It wouldn't create any problem in the future, but I recommend you check this [article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/a-guide-to-flow-in-react-native-48497ef78e99).

Comment: would or wouldn't??? how does a type checker create a problem?? check your answer would or wouldn't??

Comment: Sorry for the typo. What I mean is that it doesn't create a problem, you can start the project without any errors, although IDE shows errors related to App.js not being a typescript file.  The only problem is that IDE doesn't recognize it. If you want IDE to recognize, then you may want to install Flow or if you are using vs code, install Flow extension and change to the desired version. Yesterday, it was complaining about not having the proper versioning between the one installed on the react-native CLI project and the one extension using.

Comment: actually this question is one month old , i started this project 50% is completed, i just removed the code causing errors on app.js now it's all good